# Is there a better way to edit Excel functions?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a new job working in Excel and am having fun creating fun, ridiculously long formulas. Is there a better editor? One that can help me keep track of parenthesis? One that (dreaming here) would allow me to save the formulas outside of Excel with comments?

Comment: When I need to nest formulas I like to use a separate sheet and use one cell per part of the formula. Then on the display sheet I have a very simple "=sheetx!A1" formula to show the result.

Comment: The best solution I've come up with is to put different parts of the formula in other cells then refer to them such that each cell is a complete formula on its own. Another trick is that you can add +n("some text that serves as comments"). For example: =if(something,(A+B)+n("A is the blah blah and B is the yada yada")...   The comment (including the plus sign) have no effect on teh formula but allow you to leave breadcrumbs about what you were thinking.

Answer (score 3):

The best tool available at your disposal is the excel Insert Function wizard, but this is not good for entering complex and nested formulas. Excel itself does matching to a certain extent using color coding the opening parenthesis with the closing parenthesis, but this cannot be compared to any advanced IDE's used for coding.

While I was researching for your problem, I came across a great link which might help you increase your fluency of working with excel formulaes:
https://exceljet.net/blog/29-ways-to-save-time-with-excel-formulas

Comment: *(+1)* for a very good reference